Delete duplicate rows but keeps 1 row (SQLITE)
I want to delete duplicate rows but with conditions like
name  | tier |
—————————————|
geeni |  1   |
geeni |  1   |
geeni |  2   |
geeni |  3   |
geeni |  4   |
geeni |  4   |
geeni |  5   |

How do I remove the duplicate rows from the minimum of 3 and below, but keep the rest from above (4 and 5), even though they also duplicate?
name  | tier |
—————————————|
geeni |  4   |
geeni |  4   |
geeni |  5   |

Keeps the duplicate of 4 not deleted it (Only 3,2 & 1). Let me know if it’s possible! ToT

Removed conflicting product tags (mysql / sqlite). Please add the one back that you actually use.

    -- Step 1: Identify the rows to keep (tiers 4 and 5).
WITH RowsToKeep AS (
    SELECT
        name,
        tier
    FROM
        YourTableName
    WHERE
        tier >= 4
),
-- Step 2: Identify the rows to delete based on conditions.
RowsToDelete AS (
    SELECT
        name,
        tier,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, tier ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
    FROM
        YourTableName
    WHERE
        tier < 4
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM RowsToKeep
            WHERE RowsToKeep.name = YourTableName.name
              AND RowsToKeep.tier = YourTableName.tier
        )
)
-- Step 3: Delete the identified rows.
DELETE FROM YourTableName
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM RowsToDelete
    WHERE RowsToDelete.name = YourTableName.name
      AND RowsToDelete.tier = YourTableName.tier
      AND RowsToDelete.rn > 1 -- Keeping one instance of each duplicate.
);


I don’t really understand the Step 1 & 2 sorry (ToT)

Step 1 creates a Common Table Expression (CTE) that contains all the rows from your table that have a tier >= 4. Step 2 creates another CTE based on the select query. The ROW NUMBER () method returns a unique row number for every row in the partition.  Each row in a partition in this query has the same value for name and tier number and has a unique number assigned to it. The where clause in step 2 makes sure that only those records are selected for deletion that have at least one duplicate. Hope that helps.
